# Tag synonym request: [experience] → [experience-points], [xp] → [experience-points], [exp] → [experience-points]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I feel that just [experience](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience) on it's own is too vague, do we mean the experience of  playing the game or the [experience points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experience_point)? Since it would appear to be generally used for experience points, I'd like the following tags become synonyms of [experience-points](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience-points), as they are all shorthand for it.

- [experience](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience) → [experience-points](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience-points)
- [xp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/xp) → [experience-points](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience-points)
- [exp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/exp) → [experience-points](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience-points)

Comment: I think `experience` should be clear enough, and I assume some games don't use "points" for experience.  There's certainly no need to create `xp` or `exp` -- typing either will bring up `experience`, and no one's created them despite that so far.  In other words I agree with badp's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There was only [one question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20889/is-a-trackball-good-for-playing-games) tagged [experience](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/experience) to mean the experience of playing the game, and I removed that tag.

I don't think we really need to do anything else here, right now.